# Visistor with local IP address registered on my forum?

Tags: ip, local, member

Today I was looking for recent registrations on my forum and got shocked:

Some member is registered with 192.168.1.x IP address! How is that even possible?
Everything is hosted on VPS which is not part of any 192.x.x.x IP ranges.

I have long experience with all that IT stuff, but I have never been experienced this.

Maybe temp error? As this is only user with that IP.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed member with 127.0.0.1 IP and Googling pointed me to right direction:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22980/172-16-33-197-127-0-0-1-ip-addresses-in-visitor-logs

So it's probably forged IP. I completely forgot about faking HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header.